# How to validate hh:mma time format in Go?

Tags: regex, validation, go

I need to validate that the time format of a time is: hh:mma

Example:

```
09:00pm
09:00am
08:55pm
08:54am
1:00pm
```

I know that I need to use the regexp package of Go and its MatchString method for this. But I can't figure out the pattern that I need to pass to MatchString method to achieve what I need.

I also searched for a Go validator package that I can use instead of writing my own validator for validating the time format but I can't find one that suits my needs.

Comment: Do you need that the regex to validate also if the time is valid like `23:71am` as invalid?

Comment: You don't really *need* regular expressions for this.

Comment: @coredump What solution can you suggest?

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/SHcAHTUomW. I was just  reacting to what you said: "I know that I need to use the regexp package". Sometimes using a regex is overkill for simple tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a regex that validates 12-hour times in that format:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[012]):([0-5][0-9])[ap]m$
```

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/zP9zA1/3)

Comment: @John Whoops, I used the wrong regex in my test. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Coming into this late, but I wanted to propose another solution outside of regular expressions.  You can use the time package to validate your values and then, if needed, you can use the resulting values later.

```
package main

import (

  "fmt"
  "time"

)

func main() {

  Form := "3:04pm"
  timesToCheck := []string{"7:54pm", "09:00pm", "09:00am", "08:55pm", "08:54am", "1:00pm", "23:00am"}

  for _, v := range timesToCheck {
    if t, e := time.Parse(Form, v); e != nil {
      fmt.Println(e.Error())
    } else {
      fmt.Printf("%#v\n", t)
    }
  }

}
```

Which would give you the following:

```
time.Time{sec:-31550760, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x1811e0)}
time.Time{sec:-31546800, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x1811e0)}
time.Time{sec:-31590000, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x1811e0)}
time.Time{sec:-31547100, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x1811e0)}
time.Time{sec:-31590360, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x1811e0)}
time.Time{sec:-31575600, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(0x1811e0)}
parsing time "23:00am": hour out of range
```